# Permission Denied CPP in VSCode Dokcerized container

Tags: c++, docker, visual-studio-code, openmediavault

I am using VSCOde in docker container by "coder". I have extensions installed of C/C++ by Microsoft and Code Runner. MingW is also installed. When i run the code as per manual of code runner documentation i receive the following error. Please help me.

[image]

The error shows up that permission is denied while running it. Please help me tried everything but nothing worked.

Comment: check rights of your `..\javacode\main` folder. According to the error message, you have insufficient rights (use `chmod` command ...)

Comment: I don't know how to use it. Please help me. I am a newbie in Linux.

Comment: To make it quick and simple: go to your `javacode` folder (cd /home/coder/ .../javacode) and write `chmod 777 main` (main is the folder who containt your cpp files ...)